# BizTalk - Start 'Rule Engine Update Service' Errors

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm on a QA environment, and can talk to the BizTalk Admin tomorrow.  Apparently, I'm the first person to call a BizRule from an orchestration, and the orchestration is giving error:

> Inner exception: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.RuleEngine.RuleEngineCache' threw an exception.

I checked, and the Rules Engine is configured on this machine. But the "Rule Engine Update Service" was not running.  I tried to start it, and get this error in the "Services" tool:

> "The Rule Engine Update Service service on Local Computer started and
>   then stopped.  Some services stop automatically if they are not in use
>   by other services or programs."

I checked the event log, and for each time I tried to start it, I see this:

> Service could not be started. :
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. System.InvalidCastException: Specified
>   cast is not valid.

Any ideas what I can do? I have admin privileges on the machine (BizTalk 2013/R2).

Comment: This might be related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2015/03/09/windows-could-not-start-the-rule-engine-update-service-on-local-computer-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our BizTalk Admin corrected the CacheEntries using RegEdit.  The one on the right was the other server in the group that was working.

[image]

Comment: However did it get to an invalid value like that?   A mystery that may never be solved.   Don't forget to tick your answer ;-)